# Java swing Button is invisible after revalidate() until clicked

Tags: java, swing, layout, thread-safety, paint

I have a panel with box layout full of buttons {A, B, empty...}. When i try to remove A, I am left with {empty, B, empty}. So i try to add panel.revalidate() but now i have {invisible, empty, empty} and if I mouse over the spot were the button should be and click it appears {B, empty, empty}.
adding panel.repaint() did not help.

```
Component[] components = Gui.panel.getComponents();
for(int b = 0; b < components.length; b++) {
  if(((Button) components[b]).getLabel().contentEquals(parts[2])) {
    Gui.panel.remove((Button) components[b]);
    Gui.panel.revalidate();
    Gui.panel.repaint();
    break;
  }
}
```

I also tried to recreate the list skipping the component i wanted omitted but it returns the exact same results.

```
Component[] components = Gui.panel.getComponents();
Gui.panel.removeAll();
for(int b = 0; b < components.length; b++) {
  if(!((Button) components[b]).getLabel().contentEquals(parts[2])) {
    Gui.panel.add(components[b]);
  }
}
Gui.panel.revalidate();
Gui.panel.repaint();
```

I know that swing is not thread safe, but i am not sure if that applies here.
The problem is occurring in a runnable class that listens for a message from the server. Although i do a lot of GUI manipulation from the same thread and this is my first problem.

EDIT: 
here is a program that highlights my problem:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CreativeName {
    public static Thread listen;
    static Object VirtualServer = new Object();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
               Gui.createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
        listen = new Thread(new FromServer());
        listen.start();
    }
}
class FromServer implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
    //Wait for a message from the "server".
        synchronized(CreativeName.VirtualServer) {
            try {
                CreativeName.VirtualServer.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        }
    //Message received,remove button.
        Component[] components = Gui.panel.getComponents();
        for(int b = 0; b < components.length; b++) {
            if(((Button) components[b]).getLabel().contentEquals("A")) {
                Gui.panel.remove((Button) components[b]);
                Gui.panel.revalidate();
                Gui.panel.repaint();
            break;
            }
        }
    }   
}
class Gui extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    protected static JPanel panel;
    protected static Button remove, A, B;

    public Gui() {
        super(new GridBagLayout());
        remove = new Button("Remove");
        remove.setBackground(new Color(250, 200, 200));
        remove.addActionListener(this);
        A = new Button("A");
        A.setBackground(new Color(200, 200, 250));
        B = new Button("B");
        B.setBackground(new Color(250, 250, 0));
        panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,3));
         GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
         c.gridx = 0;
         c.gridy = 0;
         add(remove, c);
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = 1;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 5;
        c.gridheight = 5;
        add(panel, c);
        panel.add(A);
        panel.add(B);
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        if(event.getSource() == remove) {
    //Send a message from the "server".
            synchronized(CreativeName.VirtualServer) {
                CreativeName.VirtualServer.notify();
            }
        }
    }
    static void createAndShowGUI() {
    //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Button Dilemma");
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(300, 400));
    //Add contents to the window.
        frame.add(new Gui());
    //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I set up a monitor to simulate the server and it seems the problem is the thread safety. Perhaps i can reverse the monitor so a message from the server will notify the Gui thread? I don't see were to get a handle on it yet tho.

EDIT: After making sure that the call occurs on the EDT I am getting the same results.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CreativeName {
    public static Thread listen;
    static Object VirtualServer = new Object();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
               Gui.createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
        listen = new Thread(new FromServer());
        listen.start();
    }
}
class FromServer implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
    //Wait for a message from the "server".
        synchronized(CreativeName.VirtualServer) {
            try {
                CreativeName.VirtualServer.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        }
    //Message received,remove button.
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()) {
                    System.err.println("Is running on EDT");
                } else {
                    System.err.println("Is not running on EDT");
                }
                Component[] components = Gui.panel.getComponents();
                for(int b = 0; b < components.length; b++) {
                    if(((Button) components[b]).getLabel().contentEquals("A")) {
                        Gui.panel.remove((Button) components[b]);
                        Gui.panel.revalidate();
                        Gui.panel.repaint();
                    break;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }   
}
class Gui extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    protected static JPanel panel;
    protected static Button remove, A, B;

    public Gui() {
        super(new GridBagLayout());
        remove = new Button("Remove");
        remove.setBackground(new Color(250, 200, 200));
        remove.addActionListener(this);
        A = new Button("A");
        A.setBackground(new Color(200, 200, 250));
        B = new Button("B");
        B.setBackground(new Color(250, 250, 0));
        panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,3));
         GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
         c.gridx = 0;
         c.gridy = 0;
         add(remove, c);
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = 1;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 5;
        c.gridheight = 5;
        add(panel, c);
        panel.add(A);
        panel.add(B);
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        if(event.getSource() == remove) {
    //Send a message from the "server".
            synchronized(CreativeName.VirtualServer) {
                CreativeName.VirtualServer.notify();
            }
        }
    }
    static void createAndShowGUI() {
    //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Button Dilemma");
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(300, 400));
    //Add contents to the window.
        frame.add(new Gui());
    //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't know about others, but as for myself, I much prefer to see someone post a small running program, a [sscce](http://sscce.org) (see the link) when asking questions about code that's not working.

Comment: And regarding the listening portion -- are you in fact taking care to do those things in a background thread, and also taking care to make all Swing calls on the Swing event thread?

Comment: While putting together a sscce i think i found a solution. Also i think i know what NOT THREAD SAFE means. I will make some posts when i am done.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm confused as you state that you understand Swing threading issues, and yet you've posted code that breaks these rules, including code that updates Swing component states off of the Swing event dispatch thread. I can only assume that you don't yet fully understand Swing threading and strongly recommend that you check out the tutorial [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/), since it might have bearing on your problem.

Comment: I figured that the code i posted is bad as it showcases the problem. The only thing i understand is that there is an issue. It looks like a monitor will not get me were i want to be. invokeLater() / invokeNow() seems to be my ticket into the EDT.

Comment: What if you use Swing's JButton in place of AWT's Button?

Comment: Great idea! The JButton never becomes invisible. Strange behavior regarding the Button tho.

Comment: No, not really. You're mixing AWT and Swing components indiscriminately, and that can lead to strange behaviors. You don't want to do this.

Comment: Looking back, i really had no idea what i was doing.. heh.. Thank you for getting me back on track.